# Firefox bug with input type password?

Tags: firefox, input, passwords

I have a problem in an application I'm developing, if I have input fields with type 'password' then another input field is populated with data from a completely different element.

If I set the type of the element that is 'password' to 'text' there is no problem.

Unforunatley I can't post an example of jsFiddle, but I've searched around and found other people having a problem with Firefox with an older version.

I'm using version: 43.0b9 with Firebug 2.0.13

IE, Chrome and Safari do not do this with the exact same page loaded, but its very repeatable and very realiable in FireFox.

I've set the attribute autocomplete="off" but no difference.

This problem has me scratching my head...I've commented out just about everything, but the problem still occurs, some how my name and login password are finding there way into two INPUT elements, the same page in Chrome, IE and Safari does not do this.

Comment: Do you happen to remember if you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and finally solved it after reading this answer to other similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745884/6938721

In my case, I had a lot of input fields divided into multiple fieldsets, and sent them through AJAX.

Well, the solution was to surround each `<fieldset>...</fieldset>` with `<form>...</form>` labels.

Originally I had something like:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="password" name="field2">
    <input type="password" name="field3">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="field4">
    <input type="password" name="field5">
    <input type="password" name="field6">
</fieldset>
```

And after applying the solution I get:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="field1">
        <input type="password" name="field2">
        <input type="password" name="field3">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="field4">
        <input type="password" name="field5">
        <input type="password" name="field6">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Edit:

The key is to not have more than 3 password inputs inside a `<form>` block. The document works as a `<form>` block by itself

Hope this helps